# Android - get remaining time from a pending notification that is repeating periodically

Tags: android, push-notification, kotlin, android-pendingintent

I set up a pending notification based on some value the user inserts within the app like this:

```
val notificationAlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val notificationIntent = Intent(this, ReminderBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
            notificationIntent.putExtra("bytes", bytes)
            val pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10)
            notificationAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.timeInMillis,
                    NOTIFICATION_OFFSET,
                    pendingNotificationIntent)
```

Since it is a repeating intent I can calculate only the first notification, the ones after can't be calculated.

How can I get the time remaining until the notification will be shown again?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you set the exact day and time to the Calendar instance, then it'll be easier to calculate the pending time using notification time - current device time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's right, but how do I get the notification time?